# What is the difference between "modest" and "poor"?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between "modest" and "poor"? They seem similar in meaning.

Comment: A peanut butter sandwich and a mayonaise sandwich.

Comment: Report what you found in a dictionary as part of the question.

Comment: How do you intend to use the word?

Comment: Both could have several meanings depending on **context**.